# On the eigenvectors of a circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, circulant-matrices

> A circulant matrix is a square matrix whose each row is the preceding row rotated to the right by one element, e.g., the following is a $3 \times 3$ circulant matrix.
> $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 2 & 3\\
> 3 & 1 & 2\\
> 2 & 3 & 1
> \end{bmatrix}$$For any $n \times n$ circulant matrix ($n > 5$), which of the following $n$-length vectors is always an eigenvector? 
>  (a) A vector whose $k$-th element is $k$ 
>  (b) A vector whose $k$-th element is $n k$ 
>  (c) A vector whose $k$-th element is $\exp \left(j\dfrac{2π(n − 5)k}{ n}\right)$ where $j = \sqrt{−1}$ 
>  (d) A vector whose $k$-th element is $\sinh (2πk/n)$ 
>  (e) None of the above

---

I don't know what to start with. Can someone please help?

Comment: Start with the definition of an eigenvector.

Comment: Since this is a exam question and not a real mathematics question I'd tackle it this way: test (a)-(e) against the simplest non-trivial circulant, the one with $1$ on the superdiagonal and bottom left place, and $0$ elsewhere. Clearly only (c) or (e) will work. So does (c) work for all circulants?

Comment: Look carefully at the value in (c). You might want to simplify that as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.